# html srcset always show bigger image

Tags: html, srcset

I'm trying to use srcset but they don't work

here is my code

```html
<img style="width: 100%"
     src="https://fakeimg.pl/400x267"
     srcset="https://fakeimg.pl/400x267 400w,
                https://fakeimg.pl/825x550 800w"
     alt=""
     title="">
```

but at any size of view port I have 825x550 size image

Answer (score 0):

From [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/img#attributes):

> If the `srcset` attribute uses width descriptors, the `sizes` attribute must also be present, or the `srcset` itself will be ignored.

You need to give a `sizes` attribute like so:

```html
 sizes="(max-width: 600px) 400px,
         800px"
```

Further information on this [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/HTML/Multimedia_and_embedding/Responsive_images).

Comment: thanks, I added, but no effect

Comment: This only takes effect when reloading the page, not on resize.